# Why doesn't the option to rebuild Maven index show up when right-clicking central in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, repository, m2eclipse

Recently, I've been working on a maven project in eclipse. When I try to search dependencies to add in the **pom.xml**, nothing shows up. So, I went online and saw that a solution was to rebuild the index by expanding **Global Repositories** and right-clicking **central**. However, when I right click **central**, I don't get the option to rebuild the index: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Ne4.png).

I've already tried restarting eclipse, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: For performance reasons, downloading the index was replaced in favor of directly searching Maven Central. What's your root problem (you want to have the index to do what)?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried most of the fixes but the only thing that worked for me is using 'eclipse IDE for java developers' instead of 'Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).